# Dart editor can not locate java vm

Tags: dart, virtual-machine, dart-editor

I would like to check out Dart. Got the windows 7 & 8 zip. Unziped it and fired up the editor.
complained that it needed a java vm. Downladed and installed it and set the reference in the ini.file to the Javaw.exe as instructed  [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/troubleshoot.html#launch-dart-editor):

```
-data
@user.home\DartEditor
-vm 
    D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-d64
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx2000m
```

still no joy:

[image: message]

**UPDATE** 
went to 64 Bit java version:[image]

Comment: `D:` drive? Also... don't point directly to the exe, just point to the `/jre/` direcotry or if that doesn't work, point to the `/jre/bin/` directory...

Comment: The troubleshooting guide I linked to in my answer shows an example where the path includes `javaw.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely removed all java versions and obtained the latest version for windows 8.1, [image]
added the file location to path and voila.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the 64bit DartEditor you need a 64bit JRE/JDK.

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/troubleshoot.html

Comment: updated to 64 bit version C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe. New location, same error

Comment: What do you get when you enter `java -version` or `java.exe -version`

Comment: included java version in question

Comment: Looks fine. I' out of ideas.

Comment: You could file a bug at http://dartbug.com maybe there someone has an idea. DartEditor is basically Eclipse. Maybe someone had a similar issue there.